# Android studio unstable behavior and not building successfully

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, access-denied

I have created an error free android project and after updating android studio, I opened the project again. But, the gradle does not fills successfully. There's also cross on 'app' button [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4aRy.jpg). I again tried to sync grade, but now android showing IDE error with following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create init script that applies the Java library plugin
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts.addApplyJavaLibraryPluginInitScriptCommandLineArg(GradleInitScripts.java:102)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.common.CommandLineArgs.get(CommandLineArgs.java:83)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.findGradleExecutionSettings(SyncExecutor.java:152)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:131)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.sync(NewGradleSync.java:185)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.access$000(NewGradleSync.java:59)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync$2.run(NewGradleSync.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:417)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:379)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:359)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:352)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1518)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts.createInitScriptFile(GradleInitScripts.java:114)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts.createApplyJavaLibraryPluginInitScriptFile(GradleInitScripts.java:109)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts.addApplyJavaLibraryPluginInitScriptCommandLineArg(GradleInitScripts.java:96)
... 19 more
```

Is this only access denied problem, or something else? What should be done? I tried opening Android Studio in Administrator mode, but it also doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was of access denied for user. I gained access of the C drive and the problem solved.